# I am trying to iterate over multiple ranges to create a multidimensional ndarray from another

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.arange(25).reshape(5, 5)
>>> a
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
       [15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
       [20, 21, 22, 23, 24]])
```

How do I get an array which is the sum of a number and the number below it:

```
array([[7,  9,  11,],   # 1+6=7 , 2+7=9 , 3+8=11
       [17, 19, 21,],
       [27, 29, 31,]])
```

I'd like to do this by iterating over the original array.  Something like:

```
b[x,y] = [a[x,y]+a[x+1,y] for x in range(0,3) for y in range(1,4)] #ERROR!
```

although this doesn't work for syntax reasons.  Can someone please give me the proper syntax?  I'm not a professional programmer, and am new to Python.  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use slices to pick out (1) all but the last row of the array and (2) all but the first row of the array. Then add them.

```
>>> a[:-1,:] + a[1:,:]
array([[ 5,  7,  9, 11, 13],
       [15, 17, 19, 21, 23],
       [25, 27, 29, 31, 33],
       [35, 37, 39, 41, 43]])
```

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful - is there a way to do it by iterating though?  I am playing with much larger matrices and would like a more general solution. (e.g. in case I want to get element [x,y,z] and multiply it by element [x+n,y,z])

Comment: What is it that you are really trying to do?

Comment: @user2974839 You can do that using this answer, and it'll be faster than iterating. Change the `1` to `n`, and fill out the other axes with more `:` or a single `...`: `a[:-n, ...] * a[n:, ...]`  (equivalent to: `a[:-n,:,:] * a[n:,:,:]`)

Comment: @askewchan And equivalent to `a[:-n] * a[n:]` as well.

Comment: @VebjornLjosa I am just trying to learn Python by playing around with stuff.  I am not trying to accomplish a specific task other than self-education.